# Submitting HTML form data to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am lost, I just started programming and the code I have doesn't quite show what I'm trying to do, and is unfinished. However, my problem is I am trying to figure out how to take HTML form data entered by a user, and when a button is pressed its submits the data to a string variable in the sites Javascript. The challenge is that I can't use any server-side script, only HTML, CSS, Javascript, and I have to JQuery. I have look everywhere on how to do this for weeks. I can't find anything helpful for what I'm attempting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script>
<!--
function storageCheck01(){
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
        activeSession();
    }
    else{
        var b0002=document.getElementById("wrapper");
        b0002.style.display="none";
        document.write("No Support!");
    };
}
function activeSession(){
    if(typeof localStorage.visitCount !== "undefined"){
        ++localStorage.visitCount;
        if(typeof sessionStorage.c02 !== "undefined"){
            userData();
        }else{
            setCookie();
        };
    }else{
        localStorage.visitCount = 1;
        setCookie();
    };
}
function setCookie(){
    sessionStorage.c01=date();
    sessionStorage.c02=screen.availWidth;
    sessionStorage.c03=screen.availHeight;
    userData(sessionStorage.c01, sessionStorage.c02, sessionStorage.c03);
}
function userData(date, width, hight, ){

}
addEventListener('load',storageCheck01,false);
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<!-- ADD FORM DATA TO RETRIEVE USERDATA -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats your backend? PHP? Java?

Comment: You should include more information in questions and code. e.g. Which javascript variable do you want to set?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you are just trying to take a form and capture the user's input when they click submit. No need to post to a different file.

So, it is simply having a button putting an onclick event and then calling a function in the javascript. This javascript would use the document.getElementById(nameofObject).value.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>New Page 1</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
<!--
function Test()
{
alert(document.getElementById("testinput").value);
}
//..>
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="textfield">
<input type="text" name="T1" size="20" id="testinput">
<input type="button" value="Click Here" name="B1" onClick="Test()"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0460__DOM-Node/Getelementfromadocumentbyid.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to submit the data to the server, you don't have to use any JavaScript at all. When you put an "input" element in the form, for example, an "input type='text'" element, which creates a text box, the text box's value is automatically submitted to the server as a form variable, with the key being the name of the element, when use press the submit button. You can then use whatever code/platform you use on the server side to get the variable value.